# Separação de uma string php

Tags: php

É o seguinte eu tenho uma variável em php que é o turno que esta desta forma (15:00-16:00) que representa as horas o que eu quero é pegar nessa variável e inseria-la na base de dados separadamente, ou seja, pegar em:

```
$variavel="15:00-16:00";
```

e inserir assim:

```
$variavelhora1="15:00";
$variavelhora2="16:00";
```

Codigo:

```
$inserir_turno = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['inserir_turno']));

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO trabalho (turno,variavelhora1,variavelhora2) values ('%s','%s','%s')", $inserir_turno, $variavelhora1, $variavelhora2);
        $pv = mysql_query($query);
```

pff alguem me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o explode para transformar a string em um array, assim:

```
 $turno = '15:00-19:00';

 $turno_separado = explode('-', $turno);

 $hora_inicio = $turno_separado[0]; // 15:00
 $hora_final  = $turno_separado[1]; // 19:00
```

Transformamos o turno em um array, usando o método **[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)** do PHP, com base no hífen.
Desse modo, podemos separar as duas horas através do hífen que as separa numa string.

Feliz ano novo. :)

Comment: Obrigado! Feliz ano novo

Comment: Só corrigindo o amigo @lffg, no explode troque a barra por hífen, ficando `$turno_separado = explode('-', $turno);`.

Comment: Opa, é verdade. Já editei acima. Obrigado pela observação, Thiago. :)

Comment: Eu percebi mas tb nao era importante